# Why isn't Drush recognized as command?

Tags: drush

I ran `composer global require drush/drush:8.1.3` and added C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/drush/drush to the value of the PATH variable.

`drush status` returns the following output.

```
 PHP configuration      :  C:\xampp\php\php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  WINNT
 Drush script           :  C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\dr
                           ush\drush\drush
 Drush version          :  8.1.3
 Drush temp directory   :  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
```

When I change directory to the one containing the Drupal files, and I run `drush status`, I get this error.

> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-project\drush' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Why?

Comment: Try to check this site https://modulesunraveled.com/drush/installing-drush-windows

Comment: Yes I did the same steps but does not work

Comment: Try to follow this guide, how to setup a path on windows that should do it. [Fix not recognized as an internal or external command, Windows.](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/)

Comment: I tried. That's why added I added in PATH

C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/drush/drush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things to comment here: Why are you installing Drush 8 and why the specific (outdated) version 8.1.3?

What happens is that your global Drush looks for a site local Drush, finds something ("C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-project\drush") and tries to execute it.

The recommended approach - at least if you have a site local Drush, which you have if you installed Drupal using Composer and "drupal-composer/drupal-project" - is to use [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) (instead of a global Drush). NB! Read [this issue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/issues/47) so it works smoothly on Windows.

After you have fixed the path so Drush Launcher is used instead of the global Drush, try `drush status` again. I expect it to find the correct site local Drush. You migh also want to try `drush --version`to verify which version of the launcher and Drush itself that is used.

You can test that the setup is correct by running Drush inside the directory containing Drupal:

1) If you have installed Drush Launcher correct, you should get the following output:

```
# drush --version
Drush Launcher Version: 0.6.0
Drush Commandline Tool 9.2.3
```

2) If you however have installed a global Drush 9 (using Compser) in stead of Drush Launcher, you get the following output:

```
# drush --version
'PATH_TO_DRUPAL_PROJECT/vendor/drush/drush/drush' is not recognized as an internal 
or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: I need Drush 8 because use Drupal 8. I checked the issue but I don't have drush.phar file on my machine.  I installed Drush with composer so when should add this lines    @echo off
php %~dp0\drush.phar %*

Comment: Please read the Drush Launcher page I linked to - before reading the issue. There is a paragraph about installation ... Drush 9 works nicely with current versions of Drupal. Anyway, the important thing was that you chose to install 8.1.3 when the current version is 8.1.16 or something. Why?

Comment: I updated the Drush and now drush status returns the following output `PHP binary    : C:\xampp\php\php.exe
 PHP config    : C:\xampp\php\php.ini
 PHP OS        : WINNT
 Drush script  : C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush
 Drush version : 9.3-dev-g94f9a72e
 Drush temp    : C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp
 Drush configs : C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush/drush.yml` but in the project `'C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-project/vendor/drush/drush/drush' is not recognized as an internal or external command`  Please help.

Comment: Please, please follow my advice. I said that you should install Drupal Launcher and make sure Drush Launcher is used instead of the global Drush. Updating the the global Drush isn't correct. I just tested, and if I install a global Drush I get the exact same error as you. There is a reason they have developed the Drush Launcher ... I'll update my reply with expect output.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to have the project to be setup with Composer. All you need is a configured core installer-path and drush/drush: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/issues/33#issuecomment-376941969 – So that makes it very easy to use with older Drupals as well.

Comment: @hansfn when try to install Drush launcher with `composer global require drush/drush-launcher` I get an error `drush/drush-launcher 0.6.0 conflicts with drush/drush[dev-master]`

Comment: The page I linked to clearly tells you to install Drush Launcher by downloading a phar file.

Comment: Move `drush.phar` to a location listed in your `$PATH`, rename to `drush`. In `$PATH` I have a lot of locations I don't know when actually should put.

Comment: I think that installed and now I have this output`$ drush --version
Drush Launcher Version: 0.6.0
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: Have you removed the globally installed Drush?

Comment: Yes I found the problem. Was the drush file in main Drupal folder. Thanks @hansfn